# git apply: how to retrieve the ref version of a patch, before applying the patch. How to manage binaries pointed in the diff?

Tags: git

I made and have a patch file from changes made on a given code version of the project.
My changes include some binary files (added or modified).

I am trying to apply the patch to the current code version (after a `git reset --hard origin/<branch>`).
I was told to use the `--3way` apply option.
I get many warnings that end with `"Applied patch to <file> cleanly"`
some other warnings `"Applied patch to <file> with conflicts."`
some other `"error: <image.png>: patch does not apply"`

When i edit any file patched with conflicts, i expected to see some `<<<<<<<` and `>>>>>>>` where conflicts appear and must be resolved by eyes and hands, like when rebasing. But that's not the case!
I would have to resolve things from reading the .diff, copy/paste from the diff to the file, remove leading +++. Just not a way of working. Just not doable.

I think that the problem is that the code base changed since the patch was built.
Likely, i should

1. get back to the ref version of the patch
2. apply the patch
3. rebase (and here, resolve potential conflicts)

Do you confirm that `git apply` does not do the step #1, while, yet, the patch includes some index for each file ?
How can i get back the right ref version before applying the patch?

Second question: After i have the right ref version, how do i manage new or changed binary files (i have zipped them, together with the patch file)? Do i have just to put them at the right place in the local repository, before calling `git apply` ?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: The command you can use to get back the right ref version before applying the patch is git checkout <patch_file_index>. Maybe this link can help you solve the problem:https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply

Comment: Thanks @Richard-zrx. I post in SO when i do not find or understand things in the official doc and SO archives...

Comment: Apparently, `git am --3way file.patch` is more powerful than `git apply --3way` to apply a patch. I now rather use it. But the handling of file removals and of binaries is still an issue. I still have to do it by hand.